# Dynamically add argument to function in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, asynchronous, callback

I'm testing my app, I have a dependency injection system that works like this (I paste here a very simplified version)

```
test.start = function(callback) {
  // do stuff;
  load(callback);
}
function load(callback) {
  var args = ...// read callback's arguments
  // args = ['moduleA', 'moduleB'];
  var injectedArgs = args.map(function(a) {
    return require('./lib/' + a);
  });
  // call function with deps injected
  callback.apply(null, injectedArgs);
}

// test.js
test.start(function(moduleA, moduleB) {
  moduleA.functionA();
  moduleB.functionB();
});
```

What I need to do is an async job before calling the callback and start the test, in this particular case, that would be

```
test.start = function(callback) {
  // do stuff;
  load(function(moduleA, moduleB, moduleC) {
    moduleC.resetData(function() {
      return callback(moduleA, moduleB);
    })
  });
}
```

I need to make this dynamic, for all the test that have different modules as their callback arguments.
Requirements are

- I don't want to change test definitions
- I must call `load` only once per test

So basically I need to create the middle function that add `moduleC` argument, run the `resetData` function and call the original callback.

I can build the dynamically extended argument list using 
`var fn = new Function(newArgumentList, /*function body*/)` but I can't attach the correct function body (using a string) because I lose the original callback context.

**UPDATE**

The DI library is [modularity](https://www.npmjs.com/package/modularity) and it reads the callback definition to grab dependency. So basically, given the callback `function(foo, bar) { ... }` I need to create a new `function(foo, bar, db) { db.resetData(function() { return callback(foo, bar) } )}`

Comment: *"I don't want to change test definitions"* Is `load` part of the test definitions? Or can we change it?

Comment: Why can't the test include your `moduleC` dependency call? Looks like a valid test to me, to which your `moduleA` and `moduleB` would depend on.

Comment: @MinusFour that is a viable solution (and easy), but I have to rewrite all 200+ tests, so I'm looking for a way to let the "test starter" to do this job in place of the single tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the solution at the end.
Since modularity supports angular-like injection like this

```
['modules/a', 'modules/b', function(moduleA, moduleB) {
  // use modules here   
}]
```

I could write my custom callback like this

```
var customCallback = function() {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  var injectedDBModule = args.pop();
  injectedDBModule.resetData(function() {
    // call the original callback function
    return originalCallback.apply(null, args);
  }
}
var loadCallback = originalInjectedModules; // ['moduleA', 'moduleB']
loadCallback.push('db');
loadCallback.push(customCallback);
modularity.load(loadCallback);
```

Answer (score 1):

If `load`, itself, is something you can change (e.g., not part of the test definitions), you'll be glad to know this is quite easy to do: You use `Function#apply`:

```
function load(callback) {
  var origCallback;
  if (/*flag saying you need to do this*/) {
    origCallback = callback;
    callback = function() {
      /*...do your injected work here...*/
      return origCallback.apply(this, arguments); // `arguments` looks like pseudo-code, but it isn't; it's an identifier created in the function's scope (for non-arrow functions)
    };
  }
  var args = ...// read callback's arguments
  // args = ['moduleA', 'moduleB'];
  var injectedArgs = args.map(function(a) {
    return require('./lib/' + a);
  });
  // call function with deps injected
  callback.apply(null, injectedArgs);
}
```

You can even do it if you can't change `load`, provided you can *update* the `load` symbol to make it point at a new function:

```
var oldload = load;
load = function() {
    /*...do your reset work here...*/
    return oldload.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

If you're curious, yes, you can update the symbols created by function declarations (and yes, that's per spec, not "tricky"). E.g., this is perfectly valid:

```
function foo() {
    console.log("I'm foo");
}
var oldFoo = foo;
foo = function() {
    console.log("I'm the new foo");
    return oldFoo.apply(this, arguments);
};
foo(); // "I'm the new foo", then "I'm foo"
```

**Example:**

```js
function foo() {
  snippet.log("I'm foo");
}
var oldFoo = foo;
foo = function() {
  snippet.log("I'm the new foo");
  return oldFoo.apply(this, arguments);
};
foo(); // "I'm the new foo", then "I'm foo"
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="//tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: Unfortunately `load` is part of an external library and I don't want to change that. BTW the dependency injection library is [modularity](https://www.npmjs.com/package/modularity)

Comment: @leorossi: Well, I think those are your two choices: 1. Wrap `load` per the second example above (simple to do). 2. Implement the data reset as a test as MinusFour suggested, which involves updating all the tests.

Comment: Right now 2. is sadly the way to go. I can't wrap `load` because the db module is loaded as well as the other modules, so I can't access it before its `load()`-ed by the DI library.